# SQL add new editable (Not Identity) column with incremented values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table and I want to add a new column to my table that will be used for custom ordering. Not an identity column, because I need to be able to change the values after creation.

My table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ponies] (
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

With data like `[{Name: Rarity},{Name: Applejack}]`.

I want my table would become like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ponies] (
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IndexNumber] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

And I want the data to be like `[{Name: Rarity, IndexNumber:1},{Name: Applejack, IndexNumber:2}]` after the alter statement. The point is that the order of the rows can be changed after creation, meaning that when new rows are added the order of the old ones can be changed.

How could I do the `ALTER` statement so that an incremental `IndexNumber` would be added for each existing data item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an `editable column` (*not an Identity column*) then try like this:

[**Fiddle demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/138dd/3)

```
alter table dbo.Ponies
add [IndexNumber] int not null default 0
Go

declare @index int = 0 
update dbo.Ponies set @index = [IndexNumber] = @index + 1

select * from dbo.Ponies
```

Comment: Excellent! I did not think of using a variable like that at all! Thank you.

Comment: If that table is sufficiently large that the server decides to use parallelism for the `UPDATE`, this may not assign distinct values. A CTE + ROW_NUMBER() based update would be more robust.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: true!, Also, this will work up to `2147483647 ` records (upper limit of int). I think this is a one off update.

Comment: Indeed it is a one off, the data that I actually have in my real table is always below 1000 rows. I still want to use scripting to do the changes for version control, to avoid human error and so I don't have to manually do the change to all databases.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Ponies
ADD IndexNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

This adds an "identity" column to your table - which gets numbered starting at 1, incrementing by 1, for each row. It will automatically be set for all new rows being inserted.

Comment: Sorry, my question was too vague. My point is that I want them to be editable and as far as I know Identity is set in stone, is it not?

Comment: @Nenotlep: yes, you're question is definitely unclear and vague in this regard ....

Comment: @Nenotlep: also: kaf's solution works for the rows that are in the table already - it however does **not** provide any support for new rows being inserted ...

Comment: I'm happy with that actually. I can enforce the rule from my code or add an UNIQUE constraint. I'm very sorry for wasting your time with a misleading question and I'm honored to have a famous user like yourself answer my question. I will write better questions in the future!